# How do I properly migrate my question

Tags: support, migration

I'm sure this is answered somewhere on meta, but I couldn't find it (nor is it in the faq).

My [question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/81622/points-to-nail-down-when-agreeing-to-develop-software-on-spec) is better suited to pm.SE, as pointed out by another user.  How do I migrate my question?  Or how do I flag it so that a mod will perhaps do it?

I would like to simply delete and re-ask, but my question has answers now, so this is not allowed.  And I assume cross-posting is frowned upon.

Answer (score 6):

Moderators have the ability to migrate questions to any other site on the network, so when you feel that a question is a better fit for another site, flag it for moderator review and explain why you think it should be migrated and where it should go.

I've gone ahead and migrated your question to [Project Management.SE](https://pm.stackexchange.com/q/2549).

Comment: Thank you @Mark Trapp!