# How do I migrate a question posted by mistake on Programmers to Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, migration, stackoverflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I properly migrate my question](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1681/how-do-i-properly-migrate-my-question)

I posted a question here on Programmers  which would rather fit into Stack Overflow. An user has pointed this out. Further, this question has also been answered.  How should I migrate this to Stack Overflow?

Comment: ups, disregard my flag. I opened this on normal programmers.SE and was suggesting it to be moved to meta, but didn't see it was already moved..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have enough reputation (3,000+) you can just vote to close.

If not, flag the question for moderator attention and we'll migrate it for you.

In either case, if you posted by mistake flagging is good as we can get the question migrated quickly.

Comment: thanks to both ChrisF and Thomas Owens. (although the question was moved by the mods before i could flag it)

Answer (score 1):

The correct course of action would be to flag the post for moderator review and explain this. The link to flag a post is below the post's tags.